# How to reposition a table inside an Aside tag when on large screens to a Footer Tag with a toggle small device.?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple ASIDE with a Table inside I am using for a shopping cart. it fits perfect on large screens.

Now, I use Bootstrap and would like a FOOTER with a toggle button to appear on a small screen,that includes the shopping cart?

is this possible?
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap display utilities. d-none, d-lg-block for table and d-block d-md-none for shopping cart.

[Bootstrap display utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Comment: Thats correct, i have used these before Thanks. However, this will HIDE the cart on small devices. I would then have to create a second cart for the toggle section on the small device. I dont think its correct , creating 2 carts ? This causes confliction too , as if i held my phone portrait mode, the second cart would show, but if i turn it landscape the first cart would show

Answer (score 0):

Oh, now I understand. There's a property called order.
[Bootdtrap grid layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes)

You could nest your aside and content in the row. In the case that your aside should appear on the left just add "col-12 col-lg-something order-2 order-lg-1" to your aside and "col-12 col-lg-someValue order-1 order-lg-2" to the content that is mean to appear on the right. In the case that the aside appears on the right just omit order classes.

Comment: Thank you, i will give this a go and let you know how i get on.